# The right place

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I have asked this: [Can I have a QR code that will create a contact on the device?](https://superuser.com/questions/369176/can-i-have-a-qr-code-that-will-create-a-contact-on-the-device)

I got the answer, but it was closed as off topic. How bout moving it maybe to StackOverflow? or another more suitable location if there is such?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a programming question, it's not on topic for Stack Overflow. If you're looking for an iOS app, then it can be asked at [apple.se](http://apple.stackexchange.com).

If you're looking for an Android app, [Android.se](http://android.stackexchange.com) it is.

Comment: Thanks, I was not looking for an app. I was more interested in the technical aspect as of what can be done with it. I now see it was not clear on the question, but that was the initial idea. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you're looking for technical, conceptual whiteboard-style question, you should have a look at [programmers.se] @Saariko